# python `os` returning files that `os` thinks doesn't exist

Tags: python, operating-system, codepoint

I have a collection of files from an older MAC OS file store. I know that there are filename / path name issues with the collection. The issue stems from the inclusion of a codepoint in the path that I think was rendered as a dash in the original OS, but windows struggles with the codepoint, and either includes a [diacritic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) on the previous character, or replaces it with a `?`

I'm trying to figure out a way to establishing a "truth" of the files structure, so I can be sure I'm accounting for every file.

I have explored the files with a few tools, and nothing has matching tallies. I believe the following demonstrates the problem.

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 import os

 folder = "emails"

 b = os.listdir(folder)

 for f in b:
      print repr(f)
      print os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, f))
```

(I have to redact the actual filenames a litte)

Results in:-

```
'file(1)'
True
'file(2)'
True
'file(3)?'
False
'file(4)'
True
```

The file name of interest is `file(3)?`, where the odd codepoint has been decoded as a `?`, and which evaluates as not being a file (or even exisiting via `os.path.exists`).
Note that `print repr(string)` shows that its handling a UTF-8, properly encoded `?`.

I can copy paste the filename from the folder and it appears as : `file(3)` note the fullstop.

I can paste the string into my editor (subl) and see that I now have an undisplayable codepoint glyph for the final codepoint

```
a = "file(3)"

print a
print repr(a)
```

Gives me:

```
 file(3)
'file(3)\xef\x80\xa9'
```

From this I can see that the odd code point is `\xef\x80\xa9`. Elsewhere in the set I also find the codepoint `\xef\x80\xa8`.

I must assume that `os.listdir` is not returning raw codepoint values but an (UTF-8?) encoded string, with a codepoint subsitution that means when it tests for `exists` or `isfile` its testing for the existance of the wrong filename, as the the file with a subsituted `?` does not exist.

How do I work with these files safely? I have around 40 in a collection of around 700 files.

Comment: [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f029/index.htm) is that codepoint, if you're curious.  It's an odd one.

Comment: It is indeed. Its not UTF-8. So its difficult to know what the real associated glyph should be. I seen this issue a number of times when wrangling older sets of MAC OS created files. I suspect its a old method of character encoding thats not supported anymore.

Comment: What happens if you pass a unicode to `os.listdir`: `b = os.listdir(u'email')`?

Comment: @unutbu  Interesting. `u'file(2)\uf029' and 'True'. This might be the answer. This approach means 2 of the 3 tools tally on the full set now. I can work from here. If you add this as an answer I will close my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing a `unicode` to `os.listdir`:

```
folder = u"emails"
b = os.listdir(folder)
```

Doing so will cause `os.listdir` to return a list of unicodes instead of `str`s.

---

Unfortunately, the more I think about this the less I understand about why this worked. Every filesystem ultimately stores its filenames in bytes using some encoding. [HDF+ for instance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) stores filenames in UTF-16. So it would make sense if `os.listdir` could return those raw bytes most easily without adulteration. But instead, in this case, it looks like `os.listdir` can return unadulterated `unicode`, but not unadulterated bytes.

If someone could explain that mystery I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Did the files come from Mac Roman encoding (presumably what MacOS used), or the NFKD normal form of UTF-8 that Mac OS X uses?

The concept of Unicode normal forms is one that every programmer ought to be familiar with.... precious few are though. I can't tell you what you need too know about this with regard to Python though.